# jQuery each giving arrays not objects

Tags: jquery, each

I have this script for changing the target of my `<a>` element:

```
$('a[href*="Lists/Test"]').each(function () {    

    if ($(this).attr('href').endsWith(".xml")) {
        var link = $(this)[0];        
        link.target = "_blank";  
    }
});
```

Why can I call `.attr` directly on `$(this)` but after that I have to use `$(this)[0]`? Foreach doesn't give me the `<a>` objects but arrays containing 1 item each. Why?

Comment: You don't need to do `$(this)[0]` anymore, simply use `this` inside the function block, which should give you the individual anchor element (`<a>`).

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, I can't except a comment as the answer for this question.